# How to calculate average of 6 cells prescribed by a name description?

Tags: excel, select, average

Each university program requires the average of a different set of 6 high school course marks for admission. A student might have taken 8 or 10 high school courses, but each program asks for a different set of 6 marks.

For example, a specific Bio program might look for Biology, English and the next top 4 highest marks. Another Business program might look for English, any 2 Maths (course code starts with an M..) and the next 3 highest marks.

Given a table of the Program Names and the Course Requirements, and given another table of students names, course codes and marks, how could I put it all together so that I can generate the student's calculated average (6 courses) for each of the 3-10 programs she applied to?

Idea: the University Program defines the set of values to choose by naming some of the prerequisite courses? But I don't know how to deal with the "and the next x highest marks" part.

Sample Data: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gEOJRMNJGujy-ExWxg8GmE5ZLrM0xL1T-n1uCE8DEVY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you create a sample data?

Comment: Sample data added. Thanks for the suggestion.